# How to handle CSP for dynamically generated page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xss, content-security-policy

I have a chrome extension which has started having problems due to CSP changes on the target page.

The extension has content-script which creates a new window using `window.open` - let's call it report window. This window houses a dynamically generated and downloadable report. User's activity on the target page generates content on the report window - similar to an activity log which shows the headline as an `anchor` and on clicking the `anchor`, it toggles the display of a details `<section>` to make it visible/invisible, using code similar to below

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('detail-1')">Data #1</a>
<a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('detail-2')">Data #2</a>
<a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('detail-3')">Data #3</a>
```

The required functions are dynamically added to the document using code similar to below

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = code.join('\n');
doc.head.appendChild(script);
```

There are many such entries in the report window and they are not generated at once, but in response to user's activity.

This all works fine and dandy. But recently the website implemented CSP restrictions on inline javascript code.

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-6gLjSWp3GRKZCUFvRalksdfkahsdfX5aGHtECD1wVRg=' 'unsafe-inline' ...
```

Due to this, my detail `section` does not open up when the user clicks the `anchor` tag headline and shows the below error on the console

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive...
```

This is what I want to know

1. Is it possible to relax or reset the CSP in a newly created child window? If yes, then how? I know meta tags cannot relax it but only restrict it more.
2. How can I comply with this new CSP directive, given that the report is a dynamically generated DOM. Also, I need this report to be downloadable, currently, I can easily download the DOM of the document into an html, to provide a report. Seems like I might have to provide an mht report, if the scripts has to be put in a separate document. I am not even sure how to provide the script in a separate document, given that this is a chrome extension

Comment: Instead of relying on the web page, open your own extension page with a [sandboxed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) iframe where you'll put the dynamic code.

Comment: @wOxxOm The ease of communication between child and parent window has been a factor in that decision. Ultimately, if there are enough impediments to that approach, I might have to go that direction - but that would be a big change for the plugin which I am trying to avoid